# iPhone 5 not starting

Tags: itunes, photos.app, iphone

I have to solve following problem.

> iPhone 5 of which the OS has not been updated recently because of too less free space.
>
> Under *Usage*, it said that there was 0MB of free space. Suddenly, it shut down automatically. After pressing the on/off button, it will show the black screen with white Apple logo and stay there.
>
> - Letting the battery become empty, recharging it and pressing the on/off button again (or on/off button and button below screen simultaneously) does not help.
> - Nor connecting to a computer with iPhoto to remove data in order to add free memory: the iPhone does not show up in iPhoto.
> - It is possible to connect to iTunes in [recovery mode](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-an-iphone-stuck-on-the-apple-logo-2000268), but it makes no sense to install the latest OS in factory settings, since the iPhone was not updated using iTunes recently and might have insufficient space to install the most recent OS.

Is there anything I can try other than contacting an Apple store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems something has corrupted on the iOS and that is why it cannot boot properly.

I recently had an individual I know face the same issue with an iPhone 7. They were able to take the phone to an Apple store and was able to fix the issue without wiping the phone, saving all data on it. Apple then performed a diagnostic to ensure the hardware was working correctly because it was still under warranty.

If you cannot go to an Apple store, an iTunes recovery with your computer is necessary. Good thing you said you can put it in recovery mode because that's what you'll need to do, then use a computer to recover it.

This is the only option you have without going to apple support. If Apple cannot manage to fix the issue with the method they used for the individual I know, they will end up doing a wipe and reinstall first to ensure this isn't hardware at fault, then proceed with a hardware diagnostic to confirm that.

Keeping a devices memory so full that it cannot update is risky. Try not to do that if you can. Use iCloud storage or other services such as Dropbox, Google Drive, One drive, or MEGA to hold/backup your files.

I highly also recommend always keeping your phone/computer updated at all costs. Security issues are happening all the time now.

Comment: The problem did not occur during an iOS update.

Comment: Apologies, let me revise again.